# ASP.NET Core Azure AD OpenID - Token Signature validation fails on production server

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 project, with authentication using Azure AD OpenID. Authentication works fine on my dev box (windows 10), both on IIS express and full IIS.  However, when I deploy the project to my server (Server 2008R2), after the after logging into the Microsoft redirect site, the server throws this error:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey , KeyId: VWVIc1WD1Tksbb301sasM5kOq5Q
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: An internal error occurred
   at Internal.Cryptography.Helpers.OpenStorageProvider(CngProvider provider)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[] keyBlob, String curveName, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(Byte[] keyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat format)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.X509Pal.DecodePublicKey(Oid oid, Byte[] encodedKeyValue, Byte[] encodedParameters, ICertificatePal certificatePal)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPublicKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PublicKey()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.IsSupportedAlgorithm(String algorithm, SecurityKey key)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(Byte[] encodedBytes, Byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, String algorithm, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)

When I take the token received from Azure, and plug it into JWT.io,   it verifies the signature successfully.

To recap:

- dev box (iis express and iis) token signature verifies successfully
- JWT.io debug site, token and signature verifies successfully
- deployed on server (iis 7.5) signature verification fails

Does it have anything to do with the https cert I have on the server?  On my dev box I am using a self-signed cert created with powershell.  On the server, we have a cert issued from go-daddy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

This exception can also occur when the 'CNG Key isolation' Windows service is not running.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2012/08/17/cngkey-import-throws-an-exception-saying-an-internal-error-occurred-when-importing-a-key-blob-under-a-non-admin-user-from-a-wcf-web-service/

Comment: That just saved me from scratching my head for many more hours! Thank you for that!!

Comment: The last 2 sentences of that post are the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the identity running the application pool.  Not high enough rights.

Comment: Do you know the rights that are required? That would help a lot.